# SQL query to create article alias from text

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a CMS system that I have imported some articles into directly via the mySQL database. This works just fine. However, the article aliases were not created in the database, I would have to create those myself.

Can someone provide an example of a query that would take an article title string and convert it to a common alias format? I assume the query would look something like

```
UPDATE tblArticles SET ArticleAlias=XYZ(ArticleTitle)
```

It's the **XYZ** part above that I need help with to take an article title like "Is a kitchen remodel in your future?" to "kitchen-remodel-your-future'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're probably looking for [`REPLACE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_replace)

```
UPDATE tblArticles 
  SET ArticleAlias=REPLACE(ArticleTitle,' ','-');
```

Comment: Thats certainly a start to it but I would also need to account for things like punctuation and particles (a, the, is, etc). Im hoping someone has a more complete answer

Comment: hm. maybe edit the question to include that --- or sanitize your inputs

Comment: I picked the example to specifically show that - look again, its there

Comment: unless you're willing to accept the default [mysql stopwords](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-stopwords.html), you're probably going to have to build a list of particles that you want to strip, match them against the text of the column, replace them with `''`, and then use `REGEXP` to replace `[^\w\s]` with `''`. Hope that helps.